# Fatal javascript OOM in GC during deserialization

Tags: javascript, node.js

My hubris and naivety has done something terrible. I'm getting the following error from my Node.js command prompt:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->


<--- JS stacktrace --->


#
# Fatal javascript OOM in GC during deserialization
#
```

It will run no programs, even one with one line of code console logging "hello world.". I've restarted the computer, no luck. Some places online have recommended upping the memory limit of node, which I have been unsuccessful in. I don't know why it will run nothing. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

The last file I was working on was this: [How do I shift data using Nodejs and sheetjs to merge xlsx docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74401836/how-do-i-shift-data-using-nodejs-and-sheetjs-to-merge-xlsx-docs) . I had it combining 10 documents and moving 24 pages for each document into 1 large doc. I had paired it down to 2 docs and 1 page for testing purposes and executed the code successfully each time until the crash happened. Still experimenting to get the results I want, just now unable to do anything since the nodejs command prompt is as it is.

Comment: I'd reinstall node.

Comment: Easy enough to do, but I don't wish to repeat whatever caused this. If I'm putting in memory leaks or something else, I wish to know where I went horrifically wrong, or if this was just a freak bug. I'll feel stupid if I keep causing this to happen. I updated my post to include the coding I was working on at the time.

Comment: If it happens again after restarting nodejs, without executing any code, this is a bug that you should report.

Comment: I've gone to general help on the nodejs github. Uninstalling and reinstalling Node did not help. I can try uninstalling and reinstalling XLSX next maybe? I don't know what caused the problem, the bug report wants reproducible problems.

Comment: Resolved the problem. In a previous attempt to increase Nodejs memory, I had followed advice to create an environmental variable in advanced system settings. Upon deleting it, the problem has been resolved. Oof.

Comment: systemd problem, you using a systemd service?

Answer (score 2):

I got this error after setting environment variable `NODE_OPTIONS = --max-old-space-size=4096` in Windows

Any call to npm including `npm -v` `npm install` resulted in `Fatal javascript OOM in GC during deserialization`

Removing the env var and restarting did nothing.

I had to re-install Node and npm. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem after you set `$env=NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096"` in windows.Of course you can solve it by set `$env=NODE_OPTIONS=""`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar option could be present in .npmrc like this:

> node-options=--max_old_space_size=4096

Which means we might need to get rid of it too if the problem persists.

Also, don't forget to check your node version. This error could also happen when node(x86) is run on windows(x64).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I by mistake installed node(x86) on 64 bit Windows , I should have installed windows(x64).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).