# Node heap out of memory, increasing memory gives different issue

Tags: node.js, linux, memory, heap-memory

I encountered the following error when running a memory-intensive Node program:

```bash
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x7f84a71fb1d8 node::Abort() [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.108]
 2: 0x7f84a70fb678  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.108]
 3: 0x7f84a75c9410 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.108]
 4: 0x7f84a75c97cc v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.108]
 5: 0x7f84a779d725  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.108]
 6: 0x7f84a77b24c9 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.108]
 7: 0x7f84a778e9ba v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.108]
 8: 0x7f84a778fac5 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.108]
 9: 0x7f84a7770c3e v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.108]
10: 0x7f84a7b4a87c v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.108]
11: 0x7f84a74da2f9  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.108]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And according to S/O, the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38558989/6456163) was to increase the memory available to Node, like so:

```bash
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192
```

However, doing so resulted in a *different* error upon program execution:

```bash
<--- Last few GCs --->


<--- JS stacktrace --->


#
# Fatal javascript OOM in MemoryChunk allocation failed during deserialization.
#

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

And the proposed S/O [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74420667/6456163) is to remove the environmental variable that increases the memory...

Any ideas of how to have it both ways, so I can successfully execute this program without running into one of the above issues?

Comment: Rewrite your program to need less memory?

Comment: Your options are (from least labor-intensive to most labor-intensive): enable swap memory on your system; install more memory on your system; fix your code to use less memory.

Comment: @Shawn it's not my program, I'm attempting to use [restringer](https://github.com/PerimeterX/restringer) to assist in deobfuscating a 5mb JavaScript malware sample

Comment: @AKX I have 32GB of memory and 16GB of swap